# Traversing through DOM element using PHP

Tags: php, dom, zend-framework2, web-scraping, zend-dom-query

I am useing Zend\Dom\Query to get specific content from a webpage. I have an html document like below

```
<html>
  <body>
     <div>
        <ul class="abcd">
            <li><a href="">Cow</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Goat</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="abcd">
            <li><a href="">Mouse</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Keyboard</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="abcd">
            <li><a href="">Bus</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Car</a></li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

From this document I would like to catch **Bus,Car**  values.

How can I do this ??

How can I be expert in catching these type of values ?? Have you any tutorial on this ??

Thanks

Comment: My suggestion would be to check out PHP's [SimpleXML](http://us1.php.net/simplexml) library. It's excellent and easy to learn!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want all the link values:

```
use Zend\Dom\Query;

$dom = new Query($html);
$links = $dom->execute('ul li a');

foreach ($links as $link) {
    var_dump($link->nodeValue);
}
```

If you only want the values from the last list, and they all have the same class as in your example, try:

```
$links = $dom->execute('ul[last()] li a');
```

instead of the execute line above.